# General solution of a differential equation $x''+{a^2}x+b^2x^2=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions

How do you derive the general solution of this equation:$$x''+{a^2}x+b^2x^2=0$$where ***a*** and ***b*** are constants.

Please help me to derive solution thanks a lot.

Comment: Wolfram doesn't give an answer.

Comment: The answer isn't perfect.

Answer (score 3):

First make the substitution:
$x=-\,{\frac {6y}{{b}^{2}}}-\,{\frac {{a}^{2}}{{2b}^{2}}}$ 
This will give you the differential equation:
$y^{''} =6y^{2}-\frac{a^{4}}{24}$ which is to be compared with the second order differential equation for the Weierstrass elliptic function ${\wp}(t-\tau_{0},g_2,g_3)$:

${\wp}^{''} =6{\wp}^{2}-\frac{g_{2}}{2}$

Where $g_{2}$, $g_3$ are known as elliptic invariants. It then follows that the solution is given by:

$y={\wp}(t-\tau_{0},\frac{a^{4}}{12},g_3)$

$x=\,-{\frac {6}{{b}^{2}}}{\wp}(t-\tau_{0},\frac{a^{4}}{12},g_3)-\,{\frac {{a}^{2}}{{2b}^{2}}}$

Where $\tau_0$ and $g_3$ are constants determined by the initial conditions and $t$ is the function variable.

Comment: I may have added this twice not sure, couldn't tell if the last one has deleted properly or not.

Comment: Also, Maple gives the elliptic integral as an answer for the $x$ equation, but once you've made the substitution it will recognise the Wierstrass elliptic function in the $y$ equation.

Comment: Thanks! The solution of this equation may be represtended as elliptic integrals,so the tags shoudle contain the 'elliptic-functions'.Thanks a lot again.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the derivative of $(x')^2$ (respectively, $x^2$, $x^3$) is $2x'x''$ (respectively, $2xx'$, $3x^2x'$). Multiplying by $6x'$, we get $$(3)(2x'x'')+(3a^2)(2xx')+(2b^2)(3x^2x')=0$$ and integrating $$3(x')^2+3a^2x^2+2b^2x^3=C$$ Then $x'=\sqrt{C-3a^2x^2-2b^2x^3}/3$, which is variables-separable. But the integral it leads to is not elementary; as Graham notes, it leads to elliptic functions.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To get the first order Weierstrass differential equation from here you could sub: $x=-\frac{6}{b^2}\wp-\frac{a^2}{2b^2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $(\wp^{'})^{2}=4\wp^{3}-g_2\wp-g_3$,$g_2=\frac{a^4}{12}$, $ g_3=-\frac{b^4C}{108}+\frac{a^6}{216}$,$\wp=\wp(t-\tau_0,g_2,g_3)$

Comment: @Graham, I don't see why you deleted your answer.

Comment: @Gerry, Originally I misread the $x^2$ as an $x^3$, so the hint to explore Jacobi elliptic differential equations was a little misguided, it might have been tricky to get to them from here without a nonlinear transformation that involves factoring a quartic, so in this case I thought the Weierstrass elliptic functions were easier to work with and I deleted that answer and rewrote.

Comment: @Graham, OK, fair enough. But you didn't misread anything; originally, it did say $x^3$. Then it was edited into $x^2$. You can see the edit history by clicking on what it says after "edited".

Comment: @Gerry, Agh, I see. Thanks that's useful.